# onchange event of text box not working if i change text value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onchange Event Fired when i change on textbox but when i am trying to change textbox value dynamically it doesnot fired why?

here is my simple demo when i click on button i changed textbox value dynamically but still textbox onchange event doesnot fired.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<input type="text" id="txtno" value="" onchange="javascript:alert('Hi');">
<input type="button" id="btnadd" value="ClickMe">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnadd").click(function(){
        $("#txtno").val('Hello'); 
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why they are hidden?

Comment: really? did you try changing it's value and the function doesn't execute?

Comment: Could you also show which part you change your input

Comment: in my hidden textbox value will come dynamically, that i can see by converting it to hidden to text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing value of input via JS will not trigger `.onChange` events. You must trigger it manually

```
$('#room_1').trigger('change');
```

---

I don't see where you change input field value in your code.

Comment: Justinas thanyou for reply, i applied your suggestion but still onchange event is not triggered

Comment: @JunedAnsari Can't help, because can't see where you update your input value.

Comment: @JunedAnsari With your updated question code it would be `$("#txtno").val('Hello').trigger('change'); `

Comment: i got solution from your previous answer, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The 'change' event is only fired on controls when the user commits a value change. If you make changes to a field programatically then you need to trigger the 'change' event.

In this case:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnadd").click(function(){
        $("#txtno").val('Hello').trigger('change');
    });
});
</script>
```